# C# assignment in constructor to member ... doesn't change it

Tags: c#, constructor, variable-assignment, member

I have a simple class intended to store scaled integral values
using member variables "scaled_value" (long) with a "scale_factor".

I have a constructor that fills a new class instance with a decimal
value (although I think the value type is irrelevant).
Assignment to the "scaled_value" slot appears... to not happen.
I've inserted an explicit assignment of the constant 1 to it.
The Debug.Assert below fails... and scaled_value is zero.

On the assertion break in the immediate window I can inspect/set using assignment/inspect "scale_factor"; it changes as I set it.

I can inspect "scaled_value".  It is always zero.  I can type an
assignment to it which the immediate window executes, but its value
doesn't change.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with C# 2017.

What is magic about this slot?

```
public class ScaledLong : Base // handles scaled-by-power-of-ten long numbers
                  // intended to support equivalent of fast decimal arithmetic while hiding scale factors from user
   {
  public long scaled_value; // up to log10_MaxLong digits of decimal precision
  public sbyte scale_factor;  // power of ten representing location of decimal point range -21..+21.  Set by constructor AND NEVER CHANGED.
  public byte byte_size;  // holds size of value in underlying memory array
  string format_string;

  <other constructors with same arguments except last value type>

  public ScaledLong(sbyte sf, byte size, string format, decimal initial_value)
  {
     scale_factor = sf;
     byte_size = size;
     format_string = format;

     decimal temp;
     sbyte exponent;
     {  // rip exponent out of decimal value leaving behind an integer;
    _decimal_structure.value = initial_value;
    exponent = (sbyte)_decimal_structure.Exponent;
    _decimal_structure.Exponent = 0;  // now decimal value is integral
    temp = _decimal_structure.value;
     }
     sbyte sfDelta = (sbyte)(sf - exponent);
     if (sfDelta >= 0)
     {  // sfDelta > 0
    this.scaled_value = 1;
    Debug.Assert(scaled_value == 1);
    scaled_value = (long)Math.Truncate(temp * DecimalTenToPower[sfDelta]);
     }
     else
     {
    temp = Math.Truncate(temp / DecimalHalfTenToPower[-sfDelta]);
    temp += (temp % 2); /// this can overflow for value at very top of range, not worth fixing; note: this works for both + and- numbers (?)
    scaled_value = (long)(temp / 2); // final result
     }

  }
```

Comment: A few crucial variables are not defined in your code above: `_decimal_structure` and `DecimalTenToPower`.

Comment: Could you please include an [mcve]? The above code is missing various types and won't compile (and run).

Comment: Does `Debug.Assert(this.scaled_value == 1);` behave the same?

Comment: I commented out everything above (since I'm missing important vars) except `this.scaled_value = 1; Debug.Assert(scaled_value == 1);` and the assertion passed. Not any surprise to me. I am also running the same environment as Ira Baxter, with .NET Framework 4.6.1.
Important to isolate the problem areas to see were any side-effects are being introduced.

Comment: My advice when dealing with these scenarios is to change fields to a property with a backing field. Put a breakpoint on the property setter. Debug the code. Invariably, some code is calling the setter that you didn't anticipate.

Comment: @Dandre:  didn't extra stuff because that wasn't where (I thought) the issue was.

Comment: @mjwills: your scheme to breakpoint a property setter would have helped me find this.  Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest puzzles often have the stupidest foundations.  This one is a lesson in unintended side effects.

I found this by thinking about, wondering how in earth a member can get modified in unexpected ways.   I found the solution before I read @mjwills comment, but he was definitely sniffing at the right thing.

What I left out (of course!) was that I had just coded a ToString() method for the class... that wasn't debugged.  Why did I leave it out? Because it obviously can't affect anything so it can't be part of the problem.

Bzzzzt! it used the member variable as a scratchpad and zeroed it (there's the side effect); that was obviously unintended.

When this means is that when code the just runs, ToString() isn't called and the member variable DOES get modified correctly.  (I even had unit tests for the "Set" routine checked all that and they were working).

But, when you are debugging....  the debugger can (and did in this case) show local variables.  To do that, it will apparently call ToString() to get a nice displayable value.  So the act of single stepping caused ToSTring() to get called, and its buggy scratch variable assignment zeroed out the slot after each step call.

So it wasn't a setter that bit me.  It was arguably a getter.   (Where is FORTRAN's PURE keyword when you need it?)

Einstein hated spooky actions at a distance.  Programmers hate spooky side effects at a distance.

One wonders a bit at the idea of the debugger calling ToString() on a class, whose constructor hasn't finished.  What assertions about the state of the class can ToString trust, given the constructor isn't done?  I think the MS debugger should be fixed.   With that, I would have spent my time debugging ToString instead of chasing this.

Thanks for putting up with my question.   It got me to the answer.

Comment: I'm glad you got to your answer. It is usually a good rule of thumb not to have `query` methods introduce any `side-effects` or `state changes` in your code. Instead let `command`/`mutating` methods perform the necessary `state changes`. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html

Comment: Obviously didn't intend for the ToString to mutate.  I'm a little surprised that MS doesn't do some kind side-effects analysis on ToString and Get procedures to verify it doesn't change the state of the class that owns it.   It is clear that such changes don't end well.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a copy of that old/buggy code it would be interesting to try to build it under VS 2019 and Rider (hopefully the latest, 2022.1.1 at this point) with ReSharper (built in) allowed to do the picky scan and with a .ruleset allowed to bitch about just about anything (just for the 1st build - you'll turn off a lot but you need it to scream in order to see what to turn off). And with .NET 5.0 or 6.0

The reason I mention is that I remember some MS bragging about doing dataflow analysis to some degree in 2019 and I did see Rider complaining about some "unsafe assignments". If the old code is long lost - never mind.

CTOR-wise, if CTOR hasn't finished yet, we all know that the object "doesn't exist" yet and has invalid state, but to circumvent that, C# uses default values for everything. When you see code with constant assignments at the point of definition of data members that look trivial and pointless - the reason for that is that a lot of people do remember C++ and don't trust implicit defaults - just in case :-)

There is a 2-phase/round initialization sequence with 2 CTOR-s and implicit initializations in-between. Not widely documented (so that people with weak hearts don't use it :-) but completely deterministic and thread-safe (hidden fuses everywhere). Just for the sake of it's stability you never-ever want to have a call to any method before the 2 round is done (plain CTOR done still doesn't mean fully constructed object and any method invocation from the outside may trigger the 2nd round prematurely).

1st (plain) CTOR can be used in implicit initializations before the 2nd runs => you can control the (implicit) ordering, just have to be careful and step through it in debugger.

Oh and .ToString normally shouldn't be defined at all - on purpose :-) It's de-facto intrinsic => compiler can take it's liberties with it. Plus, if you define it, pretty soon you'll be obliged to support (and process) format specifiers.

I used to define ToJson (before big libs came to fore) to provide, let's say a controllable printable (which can also go over the wire and is 10-100 times faster than deserialization). These days VS debugger has a collection of "visualizers" and an option to tell debugger to use it or not (when it's off then it will jerk ToString's chain if it sees it.

Also, it's good to have dotPeek (or actual Reflector, owned by Redgate these days) with "find source code" turned off. Then you see the real generated code which is sometimes glorious (String is intrinsic and compiler goes a few extra miles to optimize its operations) and sometimes ugly (async/await - total faker, inefficient and flat out dangerous - how do you say "deadlock" in C# :-) - not kidding) but you need to to be able to see the final code or you are driving blind.